# Crashlytics startup fails: SSLHandshakeException

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

On most launches of my application after the initial Crashlytics install, Crashlytics is unable to get going.   Communication with remote firebase, specifically the "Requesting settings..." call, fails with the following exception:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics: Settings request failed.
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    . . .
```

Notably, the failure does **not** occur the first time this request is made on a clean install.  It only fails with subsequent requests, after the settings cache is deemed expired.

The app has many other server calls which are fine.

This app is running on Android 7.0, on a Mediatek TangoTab.

Here is the complete stack trace with the relevant logging preceding it:

```
2021-02-25 13:12:17.504 2720-2745/a75f.io.renatus D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Requesting settings from https://firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/gmp/1:793230499483:android:1ad53067378b1ba78df03e/settings
2021-02-25 13:12:17.505 2720-2745/a75f.io.renatus D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Settings query params were: {display_version=RENATUS_CCU_dev_1.553.0, source=1, instance=b5e39b4c777941816ff5e83fa337ca02c736681f, build_version=2102231205}
2021-02-25 13:12:17.531 2720-2745/a75f.io.renatus D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: mtk hostname=firebase-settings.crashlytics.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
2021-02-25 13:12:17.531 2720-2745/a75f.io.renatus D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: mtk ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
2021-02-25 13:12:17.532 2720-2745/a75f.io.renatus D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: mtk hostname=firebase-settings.crashlytics.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c1af229c0 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c1af229c0 SSL_connect:3RCCS_ SSLv3 read change cipher spec
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c1af229c0 info_callback ignored
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c1af229c0 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c1af229c0 SSL_connect:3RFINA SSLv3 read finished A
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c1af229c0 info_callback ignored
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c1af229c0 info_callback where=0x20 ret=1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c1af229c0 handshake done in SSLOK  SSL negotiation finished successfully
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c1af229c0 info_callback calling handshakeCompleted
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c1af229c0 info_callback completed
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c1af229c0 info_callback where=0x1002 ret=1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c1af229c0 SSL_connect:ok exit in SSLOK  SSL negotiation finished successfully
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c1af229c0 info_callback ignored
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.747 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c1af229c0 NativeCrypto_SSL_get_certificate => NULL
2021-02-25 13:12:17.916 2720-2745/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
2021-02-25 13:12:17.918 2720-2745/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b4c00 info_callback where=0x1002 ret=0
2021-02-25 13:12:17.919 2720-2745/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b4c00 SSL_connect:failed exit in 3RSH_A SSLv3 read server hello A
2021-02-25 13:12:17.919 2720-2745/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b4c00 info_callback ignored
2021-02-25 13:12:17.919 2720-2745/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=0
2021-02-25 13:12:17.919 2720-2745/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b4c00 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake ret=0 errno=0 sslError=5 timeout_millis=10000
2021-02-25 13:12:17.919 2720-2745/a75f.io.renatus E/NativeCrypto: Unknown error during handshake
2021-02-25 13:12:17.919 2720-2745/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b4c00 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake clean error => 0
2021-02-25 13:12:17.936 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 cert_verify_callback => 1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.936 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.936 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 SSL_connect:UNKWN  unknown state
2021-02-25 13:12:17.936 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback ignored
2021-02-25 13:12:17.937 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.937 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 SSL_connect:3RSKEA SSLv3 read server key exchange A
2021-02-25 13:12:17.937 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback ignored
2021-02-25 13:12:17.937 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.937 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 SSL_connect:3RSD_A SSLv3 read server done A
2021-02-25 13:12:17.937 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback ignored
2021-02-25 13:12:17.939 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/OpenSSLLib: ssl(T1)=0x7c146b5300, MasterKey=bf6b7c6bdbf4e1796e86319b6c51d69ab775f57eb2040c8743ddb20503adde96d2c4b492f9f3a7c0cffdc022c242dff7 
2021-02-25 13:12:17.939 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/OpenSSLLib:  MasterKey Length = 48
2021-02-25 13:12:17.939 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/OpenSSLLib: ssl(T1)=0x7c146b5300, SessionID=862f000085058a0f90837ee03ad970272ed2b57010cd4ab07274511c880cde1f 
2021-02-25 13:12:17.939 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/OpenSSLLib:  SessionID Length = 32
2021-02-25 13:12:17.940 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/OpenSSLLib: ssl(T1)=0x7c146b5300, ClientRandom=04b280e2eb6a545b35cbd85acff788b8bfc5249112044854079dd07ea6b205f7 
2021-02-25 13:12:17.940 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/OpenSSLLib:  ClientRandom Length = 32
2021-02-25 13:12:17.940 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.940 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 SSL_connect:3WCKEA SSLv3 write client key exchange A
2021-02-25 13:12:17.940 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback ignored
2021-02-25 13:12:17.940 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.940 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 SSL_connect:3WCCSA SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
2021-02-25 13:12:17.940 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback ignored
2021-02-25 13:12:17.940 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.940 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 SSL_connect:3WFINA SSLv3 write finished A
2021-02-25 13:12:17.940 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback ignored
2021-02-25 13:12:17.940 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.940 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 SSL_connect:3FLUSH SSLv3 flush data
2021-02-25 13:12:17.940 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback ignored
2021-02-25 13:12:17.941 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback where=0x1002 ret=1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.941 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 SSL_connect:ok exit in 3RCCS_ SSLv3 read change cipher spec
2021-02-25 13:12:17.941 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 info_callback ignored
2021-02-25 13:12:17.941 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=1
2021-02-25 13:12:17.941 2720-2781/a75f.io.renatus D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7c146b5300 NativeCrypto_SSL_get_certificate => NULL
2021-02-25 13:12:17.947 2720-2755/a75f.io.renatus I/CCU_HS_SYNC: Entity Sync Completed
2021-02-25 13:12:17.954 2720-2745/a75f.io.renatus E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Settings request failed.
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:362)
        at info.guardianproject.netcipher.client.TlsOnlySocketFactory$DelegateSSLSocket.startHandshake(TlsOnlySocketFactory.java:256)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:260)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:197)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:392)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:356)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:273)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:474)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpGetRequest.execute(HttpGetRequest.java:76)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:113)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:199)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:192)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:64)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
        Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
            ... 24 more
            Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
                ... 24 more
```

Any ideas?